# JMS topic time dependency

Tags: jms

I don't quite understand what this means:

> Each message may have multiple subscribers. There are time
>   dependencies that exist between publishers and subscribers;
>   subscribers to a topic may only consume messages
>   published after a subscription was created.

What does it mean that there exists "time dependencies"? The above says that "subscribers may only consume messages after a subscription was created", I think I'm missing something vital here because I understood that as a subscriber cannot consume a message that is not yet created (but isn't this common sense).

I couldn't find any explanation on Google, so thank you for any help!

Edit: I found an excellent channel on youtube explaining spring boot and other technologies. In particular, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgp9rGiuaUg) helped me understand the difference between Queue and Topic (also what durable subscriber is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean that there exists "time dependencies"?

To understand this better, compare it with a JMS Queue in which **the message broker preserves all the messages (till `TimeToLive` expiration)** published by the producer **even if there are NO consumers CREATED**.

Now, coming to a JMS topic, **the message broker DOES NOT preserve the messages** published by the producer **if there are NO subscribers CREATED**.

During the creation of topic subscription, you can tell the Message Broker that I **don't want to loose the messages for this topic published FROM NOW ON** by creating the Topic subscription as non-durable (using topicSession.createDurableSubscriber() method). Again, even in the case of non-durable subscription, the broker preserves the messages published after (subscription creation time) till `TimeToLive` expiration.

Comment: In the business context I'm in, we have a springboot API that is required to listen to the changes from a main application and add/modify the db. In this case, we use the 'persistent subscriber' model?

We have a few more springboot apps that listen to the exact same changes from the main application. Consequently, separate Queues are created and the main application sends the same message to these separate queues. 

It's confusing to me why we're using Queue instead of Topic. I understand it may be hard for you to give your opinion without the business context, but what are your thoughts?

Comment: Is the message content exactly same ? If the answer is yes, there is no meaning of producing to multiple queues as it takes lots of processing power, rather produce only once to a topic.

Comment: Yes the messages are exactly the same. I checked with another developer and it seems the reason why we aren't changing to Topic is due to business constraints (money & time). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Simply that if you publish messages in to the topic before the consumer has subscribed, they will not see the messages.

Similarly, this is related to persistent subscribers. Normal subscribers only see messages while they are connected to the broker. Any messages before or after the subscriber has disconnected, will not be see by the subscriber.

However, with a persistent subscription, a subscriber can disconnect, yet the broker will continue to keep messages destined for that subscriber. When the subscriber reconnects, it will fetch all of those stored messages as well as any new ones.

Comment: Is there a real world example where a consumer would intentionally not subscribe resulting in the messages being lost?

Comment: It's simply mentioned to explain why messages can be lost when sent to a topic that has no subscribers. Basically it's a race condition between the subscriber and the producer. If the producer wins, messages can be lost. Or if for some reason all of the subscribers close their connections to the broker.